# Unable to autoload by running composer dump-autolad

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

```
(1/1) ErrorException
```

include(G:\xampp\htdocs\school\vendor\composer/../../app/Http/Controllers/Student/2019-09-27/StudentController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: remove `vendor` folder and `composer.lock` file and then run `composer update`

Comment: remove `composer.lock`

Comment: not worked , 
Warning: require(G:\xampp\htdocs\school\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in G:\xampp\htdocs\school\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'G:\xampp\htdocs\school\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='G:\xampp\php\PEAR') in G:\xampp\htdocs\school\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Comment: check the namespace for `StudentController`.is it  `app/Http/Controllers/Student/2019-09-27/` ?

Comment: Check the namespace for StudentController as Jithesh Jose said or remove vendor folder and run composer install

Comment: Post the namespace line for your StudentController class, and show the route declaration for that route.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -r ./vendor && composer install && composer dump-autoload
```